# iOS 6 format for array

Tags: iphone, arrays, ios6

In iOS 6 you can get an item from an array with this simple code:

myArray[index] or myArray[0]

Before iOS 6 we had to use:

```
 [myArray objectAtIndex:0]
```

We can also create an array with:

```
@[@"item1", @"item2", @"item3"]
```

instead of coding:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"item1", @"item2"]
```

My question is just to make sure... IF I start using the new format, it won't run correctly on devices that aren't updated to OS 6?

I'd love to write my code this simply, but not if I have to check which OS the device is running and write separate code if it's below 6.0

Comment: I'm not so sure that's simpler - wouldn't it be better to maintain convention in case someone used to the former way reviewed/had to edit your code? It may be quicker to type, but with autocomplete and the clarity already present, I think I prefer the previous methods.

Comment: Didn't know that `myArray[index]` worked with iOS6 only. I used a library from git and used its delegates (following to the writer's demo) with `myImageArray[index]` in a project many times. It was tested on many devices including my ipad running on iOS5.1 that time and still runs fine on it.

Answer (score 1):

The new subscripting syntax calls methods defined in libarclite. According to [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html), NSDictionary and NSArray subscripting can be deployed to iOS 5. It also works in iOS 4.3 if you link libarclite in your project and add the following [header](https://github.com/tewha/iOS-Subscripting/blob/master/Foundation+sdfsubscripts.h). This means that you need at least iOS 4.3 on the target device to run the code generated.